# object output formatting (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object called `r` that looks like this:

```
{"friends":1,"messages":1618,"app_requests":2,"notifications":144}
```

I need to format and log this object like this:

```
Friends: 1
Messages: 1618
App requests: 2
Notifications: 144
```

How to do that?

EDIT: okay, I've tried to do something like this and it worked(?)

```
var x = JSON.stringify(r).replace(/,/g,"\n").replace(/"/g,"").replace(/_/g," ").replace("{",""). replace("}","").replace(/:/g,": ");
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will print out any object in the format that you wanted:

```
function prettyObjectPrint(obj){
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(key + ": " + obj[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

If you want underscores changed to spaces switch this line:

```
console.log(key + ": " + obj[key]);
```

With this:

```
console.log(key.replace(/_/g, ' ') + ": " + obj[key]);
```